# Relation between a family of a certain kind of function and linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was thinking of functions who have differential equations in which the function is 'factorable' from first order differential equation. Eg: Functions satisfying the equation:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \eta(x) y(x)$$

Example functions:

$y=e^{ax}$, $ y= \frac{1}{1-x}$.. etc

Now, I notice that the solution to the differential equation is:

$$ y= e^{ \int \eta dx}$$

But here is the interesting thing, the above expression has the same form of the function which is used when we solve linear differential equation [(see here)](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx#:%7E:text=The%20solution%20process%20for%20a%20first%20order%20linear,rule%20%28%CE%BC%28t%29y%28t%29%29%20%E2%80%B2%20and%20write%20it%20as%20such.) ... now what's the intuition which explains the integratnig factor of linear ode being function who's derivative has the factor of the original function?

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \eta(x) y(x)$$
First, change of symbol $x$ for $t$ :
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = \eta(t) y(t)$$
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} - \eta(t) y(t)=0$$
Second, let $\quad - \eta(t)=p(t)$
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} +p(t) y(t)=0$$
This is the equation from your cited document in the particular case $g(t)=0$:
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} +p(t) y(t)=g(t)$$
So it is not surprizing that you observe the relationship of solutions.